# PKIX path building failed: SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (Java 6) using Jdeveloper

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

try to call rest postman service with the code below
it works fine in Java 8 but java 6 returns this error.

error returns in java 6

```
  public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String userName = "postman";
            String password = "password";
            try {
                String encodedCredintals =
                    "Basic " + Base64.encode((userName + ":" + password).getBytes());
                    
                URL url = new URL("https://postman-echo.com/basic-auth");
    
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setDoInput(true);
    
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                // conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic cG9zdG1hbjpwYXNzd29yZA==");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", encodedCredintals);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode() + "  " + conn.getResponseMessage());
    
    
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
                    System.out.println(inputStream);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
    
    
                InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                //Creating a BufferedReader object
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                String str;
                while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(str);
                }
                System.out.println(sb.toString());
    
                conn.disconnect();
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonOject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(sb.toString());
        String value = jsonOject.get("authenticated").toString();
        System.out.println(value + "");
    
    
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    
        }
```

I added certificates to java 6 home through these command
keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias postman -file C:\ME\PostmanCer.cer -keystore "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -storepass changeit

and check the whole list to ensure that is added successfully
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/security/cacerts"

and it's added.
how can I solve this issue?

Comment: The target server might be using a cipher suite that is not supported by Java6. You can verify this using the system property [`java.security.debug`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Debug).

Comment: I would try to use the whole cacerts file from Java 8. BTW: The title is dedicated for summarizing your question, thus it should not contain information that is not present in your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask